# Running a jess program using batch in JessTab

Tags: protege, jess

I have written a file called `inmobiliaria.clp` which contains a jess program.

I want to run it from the jesstab console, so I tried executing `(batch "/home/jsevillamol/Documentos/UCM/Cuarto/IA/ontologia/inmobiliaria.clp")`.

This executing gives me an error `Bad slot name at token ')'`.

How can I solve this error?

EDIT: As a clarification, the token ')' refers to the last parenthesis in the command above, so the mistake is not in the file, but in the command (or so am I understanding).

Comment: The short answer is: by correcting the mistake you have made in your CLP file. -- You haven't given anybody a chance to provide a long answer.

Comment: @laune to clarify, the error points to the command above as the source of mistake.

Comment: Yes, the command above... I doubt that Jess didn't tell you any more than that. -- To fix an error, you need all of the error messaage and all of the source code that's been causing it. Statements like something "gives me an error" we can do without.